# Erro na porta serial do arduino com comunicação entre C e Perl

Tags: arduino, perl, porta-serial

Tenho que fazer uma linguagem se comunicar com o `arduino` e vice-versa.
Possuo o programa em `C` e tenho que modificá-lo para esse projeto, a linguagem que terei de usar é `Perl`.

Segue o código que tenho:

```
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::SerialPort;


my $port = new Win32::SerialPort("lib/Win32/SerialPort.pm");
$port->user_msg(ON); 
$port->databits(8);
$port->baudrate(19200);
$port->parity("none");
$port->stopbits(1);
$port->dtr_active(0);

while (1) {
   print "Enter a number... ";
   my $char = ;
   chomp($char);

   # Send the character to the Arduino
   if ($char =~ /^\d+$/) {
      print "Sending $char ...\n";
      $port->write("$char");
   }

}
```

Está dando o seguinte erro na porta serial:

[image: Erro]

Comment: Quais são as suas duvidas e quais dificuldades esta enfrentando? Vc poderia ser mais especifica?

Comment: como fazer o cod para pelos sensores no arduino mandarem informaçoes pra LP e a PL mandar novamente para o arduino, troca de informaçoes entre eles

Comment: de uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312654/writing-to-serial-port-in-perl) e veja se ajuda vc.

Comment: @MirelaVieira Você precisa instalar o pacote [`Win32::SerialPort`](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Win32-SerialPort/).

Comment: eu baixei e executei  mas n consegui nd

Comment: @MirelaVieira O mesmo erro? se sim, talvez o módulo não tenha sido instalado corretamente. Qual o comando você usou para instalar esse módulo?

Comment: Acho que agora a sua pergunta está legal e votei para reabrir. Há mais um voto de reabertura também. São necessários 5 votos para a reabertura (faltam 3).

Comment: @MirelaVieira Qual comando você usou para instalar o módulo?

Comment: @MirelaVieira OK. Qual comando você usou para instalar o módulo? outra coisa, segundo a [**documentação**](http://search.cpan.org/~bbirth/Win32-SerialPort-0.22/lib/Win32/SerialPort.pm), é necessário especificar o **nome da porta** (ex.: *COM4*) ou um **arquivo de configuração** (ex.: *COM2.cfg*) do `Win32::SerialPort`.

Comment: tentei alguns q encontre na rede mas pode ser q eu n tenho conseguido instalalo, porta com3

Comment: @VictorStafusa, concordo contigo: o assunto é interessante. Como é que eu voto para reabrir? (se calhar não tenho reputação para votar...). Entretanto: (1) instalar o perl (sugiro strawberry perl); (2) instalar o módulo (cpan Win32::SerialPort); (3) tentar novamente...

Comment: @JJoao A pergunta foi reaberta. Se você tiver uma resposta, vá em frente e poste ela. :D

Comment: ja postei,  esta ja corrigido! =)

Comment: @MirelaVieira conseguiu solucionar o problema?

Comment: @MirelaVieira vc nn deveria colocar o código correto na pergunta, mas fazer uma resposta respondendo-a

Comment: @stderr Consegue postar a sua solução aqui como resposta? (e dar um rollback na pergunta?) Pretty please!

Answer (score 1):

Segue o código corrigido e funcionando:

```
use 5.014; 
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use lib 'C:\Dwimperl\cpan\build\Win32-SerialPort-0.22-tXycqQ\lib'; 
use Win32::SerialPort; 


# porta serial
# perl+arduino
my $port = Win32::SerialPort->new("COM3");
$port->databits(8);
$port->baudrate(9600);
$port->parity("none");
$port->stopbits(1);
$port->dtr_active(0);

while (1) {
   print "Enter a number... ";
   my $char = <stdin>;
   chomp($char);

   # Send the character to the Arduino
   if ($char =~ /^\d+$/) {
      print "Sending $char ...\n";
     $port->write(chr("$char")); 

  }
}
```